# Unable to access GRASS data from QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I can access GRASS tools in the processing toolbox in QGIS but cannot browse my GRASS data (which is what I primarily need).

Thus, I cannot run any GRASS tools since GRASS data are not recognized.

Same issue occurs on both Fedora 35 (GRASS 8.1-dev and QGIS 3.24 built from source) and Manjaro (GRASS 8.0 from AUR and QGIS 3.24 from stable).

Any advice?

Comment: Same issue on Manjaro. Updated the post accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Manjaro part, as QGIS community package wasn't build with GRASS GIS because GRASS is in AUR, QGIS need to be rebuild to enable GRASS

One easy method is to use `asp`

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Arch_Build_System#Retrieve_PKGBUILD_source :

```
asp checkout qgis
cd qgis/repos/community-x86_64/
makepkg -fsi
```

Now you will have grass enabled in qgis

You could use a third party repository such as: https://giscan.com/sig/pkg/

[image]

Comment: Many many thanks, Sylvain for both explaining why it didn't work and for providing not only one but two solutions. Excellent.